# A characterization of suprema

Tags: real-analysis, order-theory, ordered-fields

The following fact seems to show up all over real analysis and measure theory:

> **Proposition.** Consider an above-bounded non-empty subset $X$ of the real line and an element $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Then the following are equivalent:
>
> - $x$ is a least upper bound of $X$
> - $x$ is an upper bound of $X$, and $\forall(\varepsilon > 0)\exists(y \in X)(|y-x|<\varepsilon)$
>
> **Question.** Is there an easy way to see that these are equivalent?

Preferably the proof should work for $\mathbb{Q}$ as well, since this seems to hold there. Perhaps it is true for all ordered fields (I don't know).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is true in any totally ordered abelian group.  The proof is very simple.  Suppose $x$ is an upper bound of $X$.  If there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that there is no $y\in X$ with $|y-x|<\epsilon$, then $x-\epsilon$ is also an upper bound for $X$, since there is no $y\in X$ in the interval $(x-\epsilon, x]$ (and there is also no element of $X$ which is greater than $x$).  So $x$ is not the least upper bound.

Conversely, if $x$ is not the least upper bound, there is some smaller upper bound $x'<x$.  Letting $\epsilon=x-x'$, we see that there is no $y\in X$ such that $|y-x|<\epsilon$, since such a $y$ would be greater than $x'$.

Comment: It's not true in the integers, for example.

Comment: Yes it is?  The least upper bound of a set of integers is just its greatest element, and your second condition ends up saying that $x$ must be an element of $X$ by taking $\epsilon=1$.

Comment: Yes, you're right.

Answer (score 1):

## **Proof:**

#### "$\Rightarrow$"

By contraposition!
$$\lnot(\forall\epsilon>0\exists y\in X:|y-x|<\epsilon) \Leftrightarrow \exists \epsilon >0 \forall y \in X:|y-x|\ge \epsilon$$
This is equal to saying that:
$$y \le x - \epsilon \tag 1$$ 
which means that $x$ can't be the least upper bound since we found one even lower!

#### "$\Leftarrow$"

By contraposition! 
We know that, since know $x$ is not the least upper bound, that for any other upper bound $x'$ of $X$ we can write: 
$$x>x' \Leftrightarrow x-x'>0$$ so we can  define $$\epsilon :=x-x' > 0$$ 
Then we use the definition of an upper bound: 
$$ \forall y \in X: y \le x \Leftrightarrow x-y\ge0$$
Now we can write 
$$\exists \epsilon > 0\forall y \in X: |x-y|\ge \epsilon \Leftrightarrow x-y \ge x-x' \Leftrightarrow y \le x'$$
which is true, since $x'$ is an upper bound of X! $\square$

Now I want to adress some further issues. The existence of a least upper bound is justified by $X$ being a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ which is a complete set with a total order. Note that not every set has this property, e.g. $\mathbb{Q}$

$(1)$ surely right for $x\ge 0$, for $x<0$ we know that $y<0$, so we still arrive at this inequality!

Comment: You don't need existence of least upper bounds for the proposition to be true.  There just might not be any $x$ satisfying either condition.

Comment: yeah that's right... i guess i just wanted to emphasize, that there are sets that don't always have a least upper bound, like e.g. $\mathbb{Q}$